# How to not remember app selection using universal links

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I am using universal links to open an app. In the apple-app-site-association file I have 2 apps credentials saved to be opened with this universal link. I have both apps installed in my device. When I tap the link, a system dialog appears asking me which of the 2 apps I want to open. All is working fine. But the problem is that after selecting to open in one app, the system remembers my selection and don't ask anymore. Is it possible to don't remember that selection? Or to remove it?

Comment: May be you have to long press to the link and it will give you a pop up with the 2 apps.

Comment: Yes, that works, but there's not a way to show the selection dialog again?

Comment: I have no idea. Thanks.